# SPM "Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable"

Tags: swift, resources, matlab-spm

I'm preparing the SPM package, with resources folder. When I compile it for device, it work ok and I got successful. But when I try to build to simulator, I got error: `... bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`

What can be wrong?

1. Tried to make Resource folder empty - no result.
   Package.swift
2. defaults variants with delete DerivenData - no result.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "GPUVideo",
    platforms: [
           .macOS(.v10_13), .iOS(.v13),
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "GPUVideo",
            targets: ["GPUVideo"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "GPUVideo",
            dependencies: [],
            exclude: ["Metal"],
            resources: [
                .copy("Resources")
            ])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by change: .copy on .process

```
resources: [
                .process("Resources")
            ])
```

It is unclear to me why its helps

Comment: It's recommended to use `.process(_:localization:)`in the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/resource/process(_:localization:) but I'm not sure about the differences.

Comment: process will perform some optimisation if possible and copy don't do this

Comment: yes by docs copy just copying the resources. But why project not built for Simulator?